# Child route not rendering in nested routing in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have `Router` in `App.js` where I have defined the url home page as `"/home"` and in `Homepage.js` I have defined the url for products as `"/products"`, but when I hit the url `"/home/products"` in my browser then I got some warning in console saying -
`No routes matched location "/home/products".`

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Homepage from './pages/Homepage';
import {Login} from "./components/Login";
import {Logout} from "./components/Logout";
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';
import { useEffect, useState, createContext } from 'react';

export const UserContext = createContext();

function App() {

  useEffect(() => {

  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
        <Router>
          <Navigation />
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/home' element={<Homepage />} />
            <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
            <Route path='/logout' element={<Logout />} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

HomePage.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Collections from '../components/Collections';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Products from '../components/Products';

export default function Homepage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className='home'>
        <Collections />
      </div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/products' element={<Products />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}
```